# Using parallel processing in vegan functions?

Tags: r, vegan

I am interested in executing the R function adonis from the vegan package in parallel. However, it isn't clear to me how exactly to make it run in parallel. Regardless of how I try to initialize it, it seems to take the same amount of time to execute. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
require(vegan)
require(parallel)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
#This:
system.time(adonis(dune ~ Management * A1, dune.env, perm = 99999))
#Runs faster (4.49 s) than this (6.7 s):
system.time(adonis(dune ~ Management * A1, dune.env, perm = 99999, parallel=3))
#or this (6.7 s)
cl <- makeCluster(3)
system.time(adonis(dune ~ Management * A1, dune.env, perm = 99999, parallel=cl))
stopCluster(cl)
```

Computer details:

- R V4.0
- Win 10x64
- i5-8350 4 cores

Comment: Curious about this myself, did you find a good way to make adonis run in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how helpful this answer will really be, but I'll share a few of my own observations and things I've slowly pieced together. I don't pretend to be an expert on this, so take my answer realizing there may be some inaccuracies in here. I'm a biologist first.

Some of these parallel libraries seem to reload the r-environment and run any start up files (e.g. rprofiles) you have **per each core**. So, there is an inherent time cost using the parallel libraries that makes it so that you will only see benefits to parallel functions if you it is a large enough computation to be worth the parallelization (in your example, the Dune dataset is really small. I'll share my own benchmarks below). That said, there are a few things that seem to help.

Using the `doParallel` library, you can specify arguments to not load unnecessary information into your session like so:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3, rscript_args = c("--no-init-file", "--no-site-file","--no-environ"))
#for linux   .... cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
unif_w = UniFrac(d, weighted=T, parallel=T, normalized = T)
unif_uw = UniFrac(d, weighted=F, parallel=T)
stopCluster(cl)
```

I noticed in my own work that the addition of the rscript option greatly enhanced my speeds (sorry, no benchmarks for this, hoping to get a quick anwer out). If I remember the source where I got that suggestion from I'll come back to share.

This doesn't help with running Adonis, however I think that initial time cost might explain why we don't see a time benefit using the parallel options built in to Adonis on the Dune dataset. Here are my benchmarks.

```
> data("dune")
> data("dune.env")
> system.time(adonis(dune ~ Management * A1, dune.env, perm = 99999))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.90    0.00    3.93 
> #Runs faster (4.49 s) than this (6.7 s):
> system.time(adonis(dune ~ Management * A1, dune.env, perm = 99999, parallel=3))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.71    0.04    6.53
```

Not a big difference on this set, but it IS slower in parallel. However, repeated with a large set I'm working with at the moment (bc is a distance matrix was calculated from species matrix that has 887 species by 3734 sites)

```
> system.time(adonis(bc ~ fmet$Diagnosis, parallel = 1))
   user  system elapsed 
 109.95   21.27  131.22 
> system.time(adonis(bc ~ fmet$Diagnosis, parallel = 4))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.44    1.41   82.36
```

Long story short, in this specific case you might only benefits by applying the adonis option to a larger dataset.

I'm not sure how important computer specs are here, but I do have a large bit of memory intended for this kind of purpose. The memory in my case is more important for allowing me to work with large matrices a little easier.

- R version: 4.0.2
- Windows 10, 64bit
- AMD Ryzen 3600
- 64gb DRAM

Anyways, I'm still looking for other work-arounds and tricks.